# Cronjob create on webpage

Tags: apache2, cron

Is there a easy programm to create and administrate cronjobs over a webpage? Something like cronacle? Also with user management or something else? It is not for a specific requirement, but I dont want to create jobs in the crontab. Also other user should create jobs, without access on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can write php script which will add one line with format of cronjob in /etc/crontab file by executing it with browser like `http://www.example.com/script.php` .Can you please elaborate your requirement ?

**Edit** 
you can add something inside php file like below

```
<?
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * NEW_CRON'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
?>
```

Comment: With which permission I will write the crontab? www-data?

Comment: file must be with 777 or 775 premission and yes, add ownership with www-data permission but the script inside it will make entry inside crontab files

Comment: Is there no other ready software with user management and other features?

Comment: May be not you can make it your own ! :)

Comment: Maybe you wanna do an open source project and do it for the community and you'll help many people also me :D

Comment: I think in your case you can go with puppet and ansible tools which can do system administration including user management and all.

Comment: And they can also administration und management of cronjobs?

Comment: yes anything you can do ! starting from installing any package to editing a file,All